# Are cue sports (e.g. snooker or billiards) on-topic?

Tags: discussion

What's the opinion on questions regarding cue sports? Are they welcome on Sports.SE?

Comment: table games (like table tennis) are on topic. I'd say if ESPN airs it, it's on topic, but they often air poker...

Comment: @waxeagle Exactly...that's why we shouldn't use ESPN as a measuring stick. They also air competitive eating, lumberjack, and fishing competitions (not that they are/aren't sports, just illustrating ESPN's diverse broadcast schedule).

Answer (score 3):

For short, of course!

Sport defined as (according to wiki and also to my opinion):

> Sport is all forms of competitive physical activity which, through
>   casual or organised participation, aim to use, maintain or improve
>   physical ability and provide entertainment to participants.

Cue sports definitely answers all of the above, For example Snooker:

- It's a competitive sport - There are alot of tournament (The famous one is World Snooker Championship), and also Snooker world rankings (similar to Tennis) that snooker players compete and used to determine the bests.
- It's an organised participation - **The World Professional Billiards and Snooker Association** (WPBSA) is the governing body of professional snooker and English billiards. It sets the sport's rules, organizes tournaments.
- It's involve maintain and improve physical ability - I'm playing alot of snooker and it required both physical power of shooting balls and standing as in table-tennis for example, but it also required very high levels of concentration and mental ability.
- It's provided entertainment to participants - Off course! It's has large fan audience and TV rating.

So cue sports answers all criterias and that's why it's definitely sport and definitely related to our website.

Sources:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snooker
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Professional_Billiards_and_Snooker_Association

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.

"How to put 'English' on a cue ball?" would make for an excellent and insightful question. If we had a trick shot enthusiast, we would learn so much about billards technique.